# How to set an elements innerHTML as jinja2 code?

Tags: javascript, html, jinja2

Is it possible to set the innerHTML of an element with HTML that includes jinja2?

```
...

codeBlock = codeBlock +
                        '<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">' +
                        '<div class="card text-dark bg-light mb-3">' +
                        '<div class="card-header">' +
                        '<h6 style="text-align:center;">' + title + '</h6>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="card-body">' +
                        '<img src="' + image + '" style="object-fit:contain; width: 100%"; onerror="this.src = \'../static/food.png\'" >' +
                        '<a href="' + link + '" class="stretched-link"></a>' +

                        '{% for i in range(1,6) %}' +
                        '{% if i <=' + stars + '%} <span class="fa fa-star checked star" style="color:orange ;"></span>' +
                        '{% else %}' +
                        '<span class="fa fa-star checked star"></span>' +
                        '{% endif %}' +
                        '{% endfor %}'+

                        '</div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '</div>'
                }

                document.getElementById("grid").innerHTML = codeBlock
```

I have seen one post asking the same thing but with no answers.

Answer (score 0):

I asked myself why I have to uses jinja2 and instead just used javascript

```
                    codeBlock = codeBlock +
                    '<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">' +
                    '<div class="card text-dark bg-light mb-3">' +
                    '<div class="card-header">' +
                    '<h6 style="text-align:center;">' + title + '</h6>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="card-body">' +
                    '<img src="' + image + '" style="object-fit:contain; width: 100%"; onerror="this.src = \'../static/food.png\'" >' +
                    '<a href="' + link + '" class="stretched-link"></a>'

                for (let i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
                    if (i <= stars) {
                        codeBlock = codeBlock +
                            '<span class="fa fa-star checked star" style="color:orange ;"></span>'
                    } else {
                        codeBlock = codeBlock +
                            '<span class="fa fa-star checked star"></span>'
                    }

                }

                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>'
            }
```